# Best way to Use DB username and password in Python code

Tags: python, encryption, passwords

Currently I'm using DB user name and password in python Code.

I want to know the best way to save the username/password as I compile the code and provide .exe to end users.

Can anyone say the best way to use the password in code?

Comment: you would have to structure this question better. Are  you sayiing you want to authenticate a user before giving him the path to an executable file?

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to **not use it in code**.

Allow users of your application to provide their database connection string and credentials as configuration (config file, environment variables etc.)

There is no circumstance, *ever*, where you should hardcode database credentials and connection strings into an application.  **Ever**.